# Abrir TW,FB,IG etc, en HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy desarrollando una pagina web, donde por medio href intento abrir las apps en Android.
Con este código, me abre la app de Facebook, muy bien:

```
<li>
                  <a href="#" onclick="window.open('fb://', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;"
                    ><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i
                  ></a>
                </li>
```

pero con Twitter y demás no lo consigo, solo abren una pestaña en el navegador, tienen alguna sugerencia?
¿Es diferente con iPhone?

Comment: Exactamente cómo se debe abrir cada app social? No es necesario insertarle un JavaScript en el enlace. Simplemente la dirección del perfil, Y ya abriría la aplicación, Si ésta está instalada, Si nó, Abrirá en el navegador

Comment: Con ese href, me abre la app de facebook, no me abre mi perfil, se abre como si abrieras la app desde el dispositivo

Comment: Claro, porque no le estás indicando la dirección de tu perfil

Comment: En ambos casos si pongo "https://ww.facebook.com" o "mobile.facebook.com" de igual forma con Twitter, me pregunta si quiero abrir Chrome o Facebook, pero solo con poner "fb://" me abre la app totalmente sin preguntar, lo que busco es un atajo como ese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para abrir una aplicación social con el perfil indicado, mediante un enlace HTML, basta insertar la dirección del perfil, y listo.

Si ésta aplicación está instalada en su dispositivo móvil, se abrirá la aplicación. Si no tiene instalada, abrirá en el navegador.

Indicó algunos ejemplos:

```
//Abrir perfil en Facebook:
<a href="https://m.facebook.com/qawithmark/">Mark</a>

//Abrir perfil en Twitter:
<a href="https://twitter.com/elonmusk?s=20">Elon</a>

//abrir WhatsApp. Indica el número en 000000 con el código de área
<a href="https://wa.me/000000">WhatsApp</a>

//Abrir Telegram: privado o Canal. Indicar en XXX el número o nombre de canal:
<a href="https://msng.link/o/?XXX=tg"><h1>Telegram</h1></a>
```

Si entendí bien, esto abre la app según la dirección que le demos.

Para crear más enlace similar, vea [éste](https://msng.link/es/).

Abrirá la aplicación si esto se usa a través de un navegador móvil. Por su puesto, si esto se usa en una pc, en computador, no funcionará.